# Is there a way to pause a loop until a user swipes right or left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I need a simple way to pause my while loop until the user swipes left. Right now my while loop runs through all my objects without giving them a chance to display, so that only the last one ends up displaying. What I'm looking for is something that will let my function run once and wait until a user swipes right or left before going through the while loop again.
Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Google has not yet returned what I want.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Based on your description, using `while` loop most likely incorrect in this situation. Would you mind posting some code about what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what you want, but the way it sounds, you want a swipe to run through the loop once and stop until you swipe again. What you can do is eliminate the while loop and just keep track of the steps through your array of objects. Something like (very rudimentary, but will give you a general idea):

```
// hold onto your position (the item currently displayed) in the module
var objIndex = 0;

// when you swipe to the next, increment the index and display the next item you fetched from the api
function moveNext() {
    objIndex += 1;
    displayData();
}
// if you can go backwards with a swipe, decrement the index and display the previous item you fetched from the db
function movePrev() {
    objIndex -= 1;
    displayData();
}

function displayData() {
    // your code to display your item on screen using the index you've saved in the module
}
```

Comment: my problem is that I don't have an array. I'm querying my firebase database and I want to run through all the pets I have stored and display all the information for them one at a time. So I want to run my query, receive a pet that matches my query, and then pause so the user can view this pet until they swipe and then the while loop queries the database again and returns the next pet that matches that criteria.

Comment: @user2888784 you can apply the same logic. You can use an array of id's to track your position and then grab the information based on the id. You can also set up something with pagination on the database as well.

Comment: I included my code above if this helps you understand what I'm asking. pretty much based on a survey I query my db and get a cat that matches what I want. Then the cat gets displayed, and it goes back through the while loop to display the next cat that matches my requirements. Since it doesn't wait for a swipe it runs through all the cats and only the last gets returned.

Comment: @user2888784 you don't need a while loop if you want to display one thing on the screen. I gave you a solution on how to iterate one at a time per swipe.